# Some sites wont load ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, proxy

I'm using a dsl connection with static ip.Some sites are not working on ubuntu but they are working on windows on the same machine with the same connection.They keep on loading.I also noticed that opening a site using proxy.org works.I'm using linux for over 2 years but i'm not into resolving problems like that by myself so a step by step guide about how to change my proxy settings or my mtu for static ip would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok ,so here's what i did to solve my problem.I deleted my connection from network manager and i created a new one using

```
sudo pppoeconf
```

if you want to close the connection use

```
sudo poof
```

and if you want to connect again use

```
sudo pon dls-provider
```

To connect automaticaly on start up use

```
nano /etc/rc.local
```

and add at the last line before `return 0` the following instructions

```
# For PPP auto-connect.
killall pppd

ifconfig eth0 up

pon dsl-provider
```

That's it , i hope somebody with same problem as me will see this post.